# xgalley breaks spacing around lists

Tags: latex3, xgalley, l3galley

I would like to use `xgalley` as a more flexible and manual way of wrapping text around figures compared to the standard packages like `wrapfig`. However, simply loading the package creates problems with the vertical spacing of list constructions like the one below. I assume that further testing will yield more problems in different situations. Can ths be fixed, or is `xgalley` simply too experimental to be used within LaTeX2e at all?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xgalley,lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\begin{itemize}
\item\lipsum
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There's been some work to make it sort of a bit compatible (Joseph can answer to that) but the default position with xgalley is that it will be incompatible with any command that adds any vertical material to the page other than material added via the galley interfaces.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle So there is essentially no hope of getting a flexible interface for text wrap in 2e?

Comment: oh there's always hope:-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As `l3galley` alters how *everything* works in adding to vertical lists, breakages are unfortunately going to occur with a lot of code. Here, the issue is that `\@item` does two runs of `\addvspace` next to one another, whereas the current set up in `l3galley` works on the basis that `\addvspace` is used to add a single 'user' adjustment. (This may have to be revisited.) Fixing it at present is trivial, luckily:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xgalley}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@item
  {\addvspace\@topsep\addvspace{-\parskip}}
  {\addvspace{\@topsep - \parskip}}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\begin{itemize}
\item\lipsum
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

which works as the `l3galley` version of `\addvspace` takes an expression not a single dimension as its argument.

Note that the rest of the `itemize` environment also needs adjustment to allow all of the galley code to work.

Comment: So what you are saying is: Don’t use the package at all?

Comment: @Gaussler No, I'm saying it's explicitly experimental so we _want_ people to use it but not to expect it to work in any particular way. We can only improve the code if people use it. I'll perhaps look to see if I can extend the patching it currently does to make more stuff work 'out of the box', and as I've noted in my answer your question suggests we need to look again at `\addvspace`.

Comment: Good, then I might also mention that `xgalley` indents the first line of a standard `ntheorem` environment.

Comment: @Gaussler 'Standard'? `latex.ltx`, `article.cls`, _etc._ don't define that!

Comment: I wrote `ntheorem`, not `theorem`. ;-)

Comment: @JosephWright: As far as I can see l3galley redefines around 15 "normal" latex commands. Perhaps one could sandbox them somehow so that one could activate the redefinitions locally. That would make it easier to test the package.

Comment: @JosephWright Also, I have noticed that loading `xgalley` destroys the spacing in a `\maketitle` and may occasionally add an empty last page if the content of the previous page reaches the boundary of that page.

Comment: @Gaussler I suspect the point is that, given that `xgalley` currently breaks core LaTeX commands, thinking about all the macros defined in contributed packages is probably ... a little premature ... overly optimistic ... putting the cart before the horse ... running before you learning to walk ... [insert favourite metaphors here] ... :-)